# How to convert a float column into a datetime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains a DateField(DataType : DateTime) and TimeField(DataType : Float)
My output should be DateTime . My tables are in SQL Server 2008

Here is an example :

Table A

```
ID  StartDate                            StartTime
1   2012-06-08 00:00:00.000              1223
2   2012-08-07 00:00:00.000              910
3   2012-05-02 00:00:00.000              1614
4   0094-07-13 00:00:00.000              1245
5   1994-04-18 00.00:00.000              2573
```

I need to get my output in such a way that I should it should validate for the correct time and correct date and append these two and insert into table B

Table B :

```
ID    StartDateTime
1     2012-06-06 12:23:00.000
2     2012-08-07 09:10:00.000
3     2012-05-02 16:14:00.000
```

Note that I intentionally left rows 4 and 5 out of the result set; these rows should be ignored because they don't contain valid datetime or time data.

Comment: What's 2573 ? 1 day + 173 minutes? thats not the case for the other values which look like h[h]mm

Comment: You changed your char column to a float? Is that supposed to be better? Can you please explain the bad data (invalid DateTime in row 4, invalid time value in row 5)?

Comment: SELECT StartDate + cast(stuff(right('0000'+convert(varchar(4),StartTime),4),3,0,':') as datetime) FROM dbo.TableA WHERE ISDATE(NStartDate) = 1  . This works fine. But I want to validate the correct time too.

Comment: I changed it since I had overlooked it earlier. And the bad data can happen. I dont now how  because    0094-07-13 was one of the datetime in my table. Also 2573 is not 1 day  173 mins. It is simply a wrong entry. No assumptions. My time field should be hh:mm where hh >= 0 and <= 24 and mm >=0 and <=59 Also 2459 should be a wrong entry.

Comment: Why should row 4 be excluded? `12:45` looks like a decent time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered correcting the design, and storing the date/time together, or at least storing date and time using the proper data types? In the meantime:

```
SELECT StartDate + STUFF(RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(StartTime), 4), 3, 0, ':') 
  FROM dbo.table
  WHERE ISDATE(StartDate) = 1 AND CONVERT(INT, StartTime) < 2400

  -- wow what a bunch of absolute garbage data you have
  -- what Government agency are you paying to provide this data?

  AND CONVERT(INT, StartTime) % 100 BETWEEN 0 AND 59;
```

Comment: you have mentioned Convert(int,StartTime) < 2400. But 2372 is not a correct date format rt?

Comment: Also, I would not be able to correct it to a proper datatype since this is a Staging DB. I need to correc the date from my Source into a proper format and insert into my Target Database

Comment: I have to make some assumptions here that you're not going to try to put garbage into your database. Garbage in, garbage out, sorry. What should 2372 be converted to get it into "a proper format"?

Comment: 2372 should be simply ignored.

Comment: Wasnt that clear in the question I have raised that we need to simply ignore rows for ID = 4 and 5 since the data is simply invalid. Also, you can use some appropriate language to discuss in a forum. I was just merely explaining a scenario that can happen and what must be done to handle it.

Comment: @user1483122 no, it was not. You showed three rows of output but you didn't specify why you left out rows 4 and 5. I assumed you were just showing the first three rows as examples. And I wasn't the only one who thought that you expected 2573 to be converted to a valid time. Please state your requirements clearly so that people don't have to make assumptions or badger you with questions.

Comment: @user1483122 what bad language did I use? "Garbage"? You've never heard that term used for bad data before? Give me a break.