# How to convert float column to datetime?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains a DateField(DataType : Float)

```
41477.637634537,
41477.6376233333,
41477.637631794
```

I need this in datetime YY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS format

I tried the ALTER function

```
ALTER TABLE HISTORY
    ALTER COLUMN DATETIMESTAMP DATETIME
```

but, the day it returns is one day ahead though the time is correct.

I want to then use

```
Select * from History
    where Tag LIKE '%tagname%' AND DateTimeStamp > '2013/7/24 14:23:00'
```

Please suggest if sometihng is incorrect in my Alter statement - or if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649154/how-to-convert-a-float-column-into-a-datetime

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using Excel dates.  These are counting since "Jan 0th, 1900" (aka 1899-12-31).

You can convert them by adding the value to that date:

```
select cast('1899-12-31' as datetime) + 41477.637634537;
```

I don't know why the built-in conversion would be off-by-1.

EDIT:

On SQL Server 2008, the following returns three dates and times:

```
with t as (
      select 41477.637634537 as col union all
      select 41477.6376233333 union all
      select 41477.637631794
     )
select cast('1899-12-31' as datetime) + col
from t;
```

Comment: IIRC, the internal format in SQL Server is based on 1900-01-01, so if you're right about the Excel dates, that would explain the off-by-1 issue.

Comment: @JonSeigel . . . That actually rings a bell.  It is amazing that two software products by the same company could have such an important and subtle incompatibility.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks! how do I generalise this for entire column

Comment: @user2616868 . . . You replace the constant `41477.637634537` with the name of the column.  I think the best approach is to add a *new* column in for the value and then update the value into that column.

Comment: @gordonlinoff I tried doing select cast('1899-12-31' as datetime) + column_name from table_name but it just returns blank value